# How to flash binary code to the NUCLEO-F207ZG device?

Tags: stm32, flash, linux, nucleo, st

When I want to upload a binary file `executable.bin` to the STM32F407G device, I connect it to the PC using the mini-USB cable and execute the command

```
sudo st-flash write executable.bin 0x08000000
```

Now I want to upload the binary file in a similar way to the NUCLEO-F207ZG device:

[image]

but this time `sudo st-flash write executable.bin 0x08000000` throws an error

```
st-flash 1.6.1
2020-07-14T18:42:02 WARN common.c: unknown chip id! 0x374b
Failed to connect to target
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

I also installed `pyocd` command to flash the code. `pyocd list` returns the following information about the device:

```
Probe          Unique ID                 
STM32 STLink   066DFF485550755187123543
```

On the physical device, I see a number `F207ZG` and one target in
the `pyocd list --target` is `stm32f207zg`, thus I try to
flash the code with the following command:

```
pyocd flash --target stm32f207zg -0connect_mode=under-reset --base-address 0x08000000 executable.bin
```

but receive an error:

```
pyocd.core.exceptions.ProbeError: STLink error (9): Get IDCODE error
```

**What am I doing wrong in this case**?

Comment: This is very odd.. 0x374b is the USB PID of an ST/LINK V2-1 as found on the Nucleo boards.  It is _not_ the target ID for an F2 chip which is what that line from common.c *should* be printing.   Perhaps you have a buggy build which is somehow mixing up the USB ID of the interface with the chip id of the target.  Try a another tool such as OpenOCD or PyOCD or even for the moment use the silly drag-and-drop fake mass storage mechanism which the Nucleo boards support.

Comment: Which USB connectors on the boards are you using? The USB for ST-LINK, or the USB for target MCU? Also, what is st-flash program? Does CubeProg from ST work  for you?

Comment: Based on the message, they'd have had to have plugged into the ST/Llink USB connector

Comment: Just to be on the safe side: you have built the firmware / binary file specifically for the STM32F207ZG and are not trying to upload the binary file built for STM32F407G?

Comment: @Codo for both cases I compile the code using the `make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi-` command. But the problem is that I can't even flash the code to the STM32F207G device, let alone running it.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand... Somewhere in your project the specific MCU must be defined as the STM32F207G and STM32F407 are different: Cortex-M4 vs Cortex-M3, possibly different memory size and layout etc. Do you have two separate projects or project configurations and do they specify the correct MCU?

Comment: @Codo I don't have any specification, but the problem I am stuck at the moment: how to upload any bits to the memory of STM32F207G?

Comment: What's the output of `st-info --probe` and `st-info --chipid`?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that on the device, ST-LINK pins are connected:

[image]

then `sudo st-flash write executable.bin 0x08000000` should succeed.